# How is two sets $A$,$B$ that has $A\subset B$ has the property $A-B=\emptyset$ although $\emptyset$ is subset of $A$,$B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If the $\emptyset $ is a subset of any set
then how does two non empty sets st $A$,$B$ that has $A\subset B$ ,have the property $A-B=\emptyset$ isn't that a contradictions? If not what did I get wrong?

Comment: $\emptyset$ is a ***subset*** of $A$ but not an ***element*** of $A$. Do not confuse "$\subseteq$" with "$\in$".

Comment: @dxiv you are right, thank you for that

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ have no common elements, then $A \setminus B = A$, not $\varnothing$.

Comment: @Robert Shore sorry for this error , I will edit the post

Comment: Yes, if $A\subset B$ then $A-B=\emptyset$. How do you expect us to tell you what you got wrong, when you haven't told us why you think $A-B=\emptyset$ is problematic? Why do you think it's a contradiction? What do you think it contradicts? And what does the fact that $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set have to do with it?

Comment: @user14111
I confuse $\in$ with $\subset$ , I thought if $\emptyset \subset A$ then $\emptyset$ is part of the 2 sets and hence the difference can't be$\emptyset$

Comment: @Ahmed Suppose $\emptyset$ happened to be an **element** of $A$ and also of $B$, it still wouldn't be an element of $A-B$.

Comment: @user14111
and this why I thought it would be a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Since $\;A\subset B\;,\;$ any element of $\,A\,$ is also an element of $\,B\,,\;$ hence there does not exist any element $\,x\,$ such that $\,x\in A\,$ and $\,x\not\in B\,,\;$ consequently the set $\,A-B=\big\{x\;|\;x\in A\,\land\,x\not\in B\big\}\,$ cannot contain any element, so it is the empty set $\,\emptyset\,.$